# Multimedia Streaming: Users connecting with multiple tabs

Tags: streaming, flash, wowza

We're writing a streaming service using wowza as our streaming server with a flash applet on the client.  A recent concern we've had is a single client accessing the same stream from multiple tabs.  In this scenario, we want to save bandwidth by sending the client only one copy of the stream.

How is this problem typically handled?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible for multiple technical reasons. This is my personal opinion, so experts can correct me if I am wrong)

- The flash players on multiple tabs are not aware of each other and they can't be associated with each other on Wowza Streaming Engine side either. Wowza would see 2 different clients from the same IP, but that might be two different devices behind the same router.
- The browser tabs are usually isolated from each other in the browser implementations for security and stability reasons, not allowing cross-browser data sharing
- The 2 players are not in perfect sync, started at different points in time and lags, buffering might also introduce time shift

I haven't seen any attempt to reduce bandwidth in this scenario. There are solutions to prevent users from playing multiple streams in parallel though, which I would not like to link here, but do a search for "wowza forbidding concurrent stream" and you'll find it.

I think what you thought of is multicast streaming, where network packets are broadcast over the network and every player receives the same stream. This is used in IP TV systems, but that is not possible over internet, only on intranet.